# Unable to configure wireless/bluetooth on laptop

Tags: wireless, networking, laptop, bluetooth, hp

I have an HP Compaq nx7400 laptop that has previously been running Windows 7. Since I have an additional PC with Windows 7 that serves as my main tool, I have decided to try the latest Ubuntu 13.10 on the laptop, and have installed it from a DVD as a complete replacement for my previous OS. Linux is now the sole OS running on the laptop. However I have a few problems that I can't solve - I should point out that I am new to Linux.

1) **The laptop's bluetooth cannot be turned on.** Linux states that it is turned off by a hardware switch, which is true - there is a bluetooth switch on the device, however no matter what I do the switch does not respond to being pressed at all. Note: Bluetooth was working on Windows 7 just yesterday and I have always kept it turned ON.

2) **I cannot connect to my wireless router.** Enable Networking is ON if you click on the wifi icon up in the status bar. However, when going to System Settings and clicking Network, the new window opens only for a split second and then instantly closes, too fast to even read what it says. I have tried about a dozen times.

3) **I can't get the MAC address through terminal.** I think the terminal isn't outputting what it should when I run the ifconfig command:

```
ifconfig
lo          Link encap:Local Loopback
            inet addr:127.0.0.1 Mask:255.0.0.0
            inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
            UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
            RX packets:137 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
            TX packets:137 erros:0 dropped: 0 overruns:0 carrier:0
            collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
            RX bytes:11575 (11.5 KB)  TX bytes:11575 (11.5 KB)
```

One last thing, after installing the OS and choosing shut down because I didn't have anything to do yet, the laptop eventually reached a state where it had a black screen and a bunch of command lines and it remained like that for an hour. I had to hold the power button to shut down the laptop completely.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks! :)

EDIT: I forgot to add that both my Ethernet and Network controllers are by Broadcom. I think this might be closely related to the problem but I couldn't find a solution on Google :/

Answer (score 0):

Connect by cable

- Update by terminal then upgrade sudo apt-get update ; sudo apt-get upgrade
- restart you laptop check if work and check Fn+F2

if not work ,Try

- install Additional Drivers [Additional Drivers](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/quantal/jockey-kde/)
- Open it and update the Drivers

Comment: That could have been a bit more detailed (remember first time Linux user), but I will do my best and try this as soon as I am able. Thanks!

Comment: - Open  SoftwareCenter on ubuntu
- Search on Additional Drivers
- click install
- after installed open the application and choose the driver that you want to install